# Symfony4 how to create mutiple form table in buildForm that use "for" or "foreach"

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have a question that If i have two variables $num,$points.

I want to creat "$points" form table in buildform(FormBuilderInterface) that the num is same with $num

> If $num is 3
>
> creat 3 form table
>
> point1 = 4 (user can input) point2 = 2 point3 = 3

then i need to save them into the same table column and use json
like {"points":["4","2","3"]}

How can i do it??

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `$num` to `$options` and then in your form type add an event listener to the `$builder`. There you can loop as many as `$num` times and add a `$point`. However those will have to be unmapped and you will have to get and set the data manually.

[More into on form events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html)